# Finding the density function given the conditional.

Tags: probability

I have the following conditional density function:

$f_{Y \vert X = x}(y) \sim Normal(0,\frac{1}{x})$

I also know that $ X \sim \Gamma(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

I want to find the density of just $f_Y$.

My problem is that I do not know the joint density of X and Y, so I do not know formulas to solve this. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
f_Y(y)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}x=\int f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)\ \mathrm{d}x.
$$

By this formula, we get
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)=\frac{x^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{xy^2}{2}}\frac{2^{3/2}}{\Gamma(3/2)}x^{1/2}e^{-2x},
$$ for $x>0$. Integrating over $x$ yields
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{16}{\pi(y^2+4)^2}.
$$Identities $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ and $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ is used for simplification.